# How to read multipart/form-data header from ServletInputStream and load content into a temp file

Tags: java, inputstream, resteasy, undertow

I have a WebService to post a file in the database, and I really need to display the body of the HTTP request to check if the client's implementations are correct.
I tried the undertow filter configuration on my Wildfly server, it gives some informations but not multipart/form-data header, so I used a **RequestLoggingFilter** class that implements **ContainerRequestFilter** to log the body when the resteasy facade is used.

My facade is annotated with this :

```java
    @POST
    @Logged
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

Its working but when I use the ServletInputStream to display the body, I'm loading the whole file in RAM. In case I use a "big" file, my method will throw an exception, and the facade will not get an open InputStream.

```xml
11:21:58,943 TRACE [project.ws.utils.RequestLoggingFilter] (default task-1) Error bodyio.undertow.server.RequestTooBigException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760
11:21:58,945 TRACE [project.ws.utils.RequestLoggingFilter] (default task-1) --------------------------------------------------------
11:21:58,954 WARN  [org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeEntity] (default task-1) Unexpected end of headers detected. Higher level boundary detected or EOF reached.
11:21:58,956 WARN  [org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeEntity] (default task-1) Invalid header encountered
11:21:58,960 WARN  [org.apache.james.mime4j.parser.MimeEntity] (default task-1) Body part ended prematurely. Boundary detected in header or EOF reached.
11:21:58,970 ERROR [project.ws.handler.exceptions.GlobalExceptionMapper] (default task-1) RESTEASY007500: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007500: Could find no Content-Disposition header within part
```

log class :

```java
@Logged
@Provider
public class RequestLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{
    
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestLoggingFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (!LOGGER.isTraceEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        LOGGER.trace("--------------------------------------------------------");
        LOGGER.trace("URI=" + requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
        LOGGER.trace("Content length=" + requestContext.getLength());
        LOGGER.trace("Content type=" + requestContext.getMediaType());
        LOGGER.trace("Methode=:" + requestContext.getMethod());
        LOGGER.trace("Cookies=:" + requestContext.getCookies());
        LOGGER.trace("MediaTypes=" + requestContext.getAcceptableMediaTypes());
        LOGGER.trace("AceptableLanguages=" + requestContext.getAcceptableLanguages());
        LOGGER.trace("Date=" + requestContext.getDate());
        LOGGER.trace("   Header:");
        requestContext.getHeaders().forEach((key, value) -> {
            LOGGER.trace("       header=" + key + " : " + value);
        });
        try {
            if (requestContext.hasEntity()) {
                String result = IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                LOGGER.trace("   Body:");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(result);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    LOGGER.trace("        " + scanner.nextLine());
                }
                scanner.close();
                requestContext.setEntityStream(CharSource.wrap(result).asByteSource(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).openStream());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.trace("Error body" + e);
        }
        LOGGER.trace("--------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

logs :

```xml
 --------------------------------------------------------
URI=/reception
Content length=259
Content type=multipart/form-data;boundary="----=_Part_43_341076338.1636107376952"
Methode=:POST
Cookies=:{}
MediaTypes=[*/*]
AceptableLanguages=[]
Date=null
    Header:
       header=Accept-Encoding : [gzip,deflate]
       header=apiKey : [test]
       header=Connection : [Keep-Alive]
       header=Content-Length : [259]
       header=Content-Type : [multipart/form-data; boundary="----=_Part_43_341076338.1636107376952"]
       header=Host : [localhost:9000]
       header=MIME-Version : [1.0]
       header=User-Agent : [Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)]
    Body:
        
         ------=_Part_43_341076338.1636107376952
         Content-Type: text/plain; charset=Cp1252; name=file3.tmp
         Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
         Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file3.tmp"         
        ------=_Part_43_341076338.1636107376952--
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I use the ServletInputStream  in the ContainerRequestFilter without loading the whole file, log the multipart/form-data header and let the InputStream open for the facade ? (Java 8)

Comment: You're only option is going to read the input stream in chunks and possibly just stop after the buffer gets too big.

Comment: Thanks James that helped me.